# How can I pass jsessionid between two applications connected to the CAS?

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas, httpbuilder

I have a problem with my current architecture.

I have the following architecture:

[image]

API (rest): Grails Application

"App-2":  Grails Application (use Http Builder)

Both applications (API & App-2) use the CAS server for authentication, so I installed the

plugin "Spring-security-cas1.0.5" in both applications.

Both applications are authenticated on the CAS but they do not have the same session as each

application generates its own JSESSIONID.

I tried to intercept the Api jsessionid from the "App-2"  and send it in the header of each

request, but it did not work.

Any ideas or suggestions, please?

Many  Thanks

Comment: Use something like Terracotta for web sessions.

Comment: Can you explain why you want them to have the same session Id. And perhaps clarify what you're trying to do overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred when we added the @Secured(['ROLE_USER']) on the controller application Rest.

If we want to get to the API through http builder from the application 2. There will be a rediraction to CAS authentifcation page.